# Printing out selected data from a .txt file in c++

Tags: c++, stream

I wonder how can print out a selected data from a `.txt` file.

For example this is my `input.txt` file content. The following sample data is in the form of `[date] [error_type] [ip_address]`

```sh
[Wed Oct 11 2017] [error] [127.0.0.1] -client denied.
[Thu Oct 12 2017] [alert] [127.0.0.2] -user name not found.
```

I was asked to write a code fragment that will printout the error_type and ip_address from file.
This is my code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    ifstream in;
    in.open("input.txt");
    char ch,x;   //ch=[ , x=.
    string er;  //er=error
    int a,b,c;  //a=127,b=0,c=1
    in>>ch>>er>>ch;
    cout<<ch<<er<<ch<<ch<<a<<x<<b<<x<<b<<c<<ch;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this code is it doesn't read the right data and only gave me random numbers.

I hope anyone would lend me a hand cause I just learnt to code for 4 months. So,everything seems complicated to me.

Comment: the file format does not match the code. You first read the `[error]` but the file has first a date

Comment: a,b and c are not read, nor initialized, there are your 'random' numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not initialized. At the beginning each variable can contain each possible value. In line

```
in >> ch >> er >> ch;
```

you read one char, one string and one char again.

The first line of your file is

```
[Wed Oct 11 2017] [error] [127.0.0.1] -client denied.
```

So first you read the first char `ch = '[` and set the cursor to the next position. Next you read a string until whitespace: `er = "Wed"`. Next you read again a char `ch = 'O'`

The cursor now points to

```
[Wed Oct 11 2017] [error] [127.0.0.1] -client denied.
      ^
```

Then you print your data. As you didn't read the variables you get random numbers.

The output of

```
cout << ch << er << ch << ch << a << x << b << x << b << c << ch;
```

should be

```
OWedOOXCYCYZO
```

where X Y and Z are random interger numbers and C is a random character.

You should instead read the whole line and parse it (e.g. split at ']'). You should initialize and/or read all your variables. `x, a, b, c` are not set. It is not possible to say which values they contain.

This is a possible solution to read the log entry.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    stringstream in("[Wed Oct 11 2017] [error] [127.0.0.1] -client denied.\n[Thu Oct 12 2017] [alert] [127.0.0.2] -user name not found.");
    string line;
    getline(in, line);
    int startpos = line.find('[') + 1;
    int endpos = line.find(']');
    string date(line.substr(startpos, endpos-startpos));
    cout << "Date:\t\t" << date << endl;
    startpos = line.find('[', endpos) + 1;
    endpos = line.find(']', startpos);
    string type(line.substr(startpos, endpos-startpos));
    cout << "Type:\t\t" << type << endl;
    startpos = line.find('[', endpos) + 1;
    endpos = line.find(']', startpos);
    string ip(line.substr(startpos, endpos-startpos));
    cout << "IP:\t\t" << ip << endl;
    string message(line.substr(endpos + 2));
    cout << "Message:\t" << message << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Date:       Wed Oct 11 2017
Type:       error
IP:         127.0.0.1
Message:    -client denied.
```

Comment: string until whitespace is "Wed" only, no?

Comment: yes >> string reads up to a separator. It is not the best way to do because at the end of the line the number of word is variable, better to read all the line in a string then extract  expected sub strings

Comment: @bruno disagree whith what you say. Simply use `]` as seperator and it should work

Comment: @user463035818 we cannot agree all the time, we have each our preferences :)

Comment: @bruno sure, some ppl think disagreement is something bad. imho it would be terrible if everybody would agree on everything all the time ;)

Comment: Technically they're not just "random numbers", the values are unspecified (not arbitrary, unspecified!) and reading them has undefined behaviour and thus the entire thing is literally meaningless. But you're right that in practice you're just going to see "gumpf" as a result with no other side effects